# SQL error - Multi part identifier cannot be bound, and cannot convert nvarchar to float

Tags: sql

I have a query which gives me an error

> The Multi part identifier A.fieldname cannot be bound

The query is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    A.FYEARNAME, A.FQUARTER, A.FMONTHNAME, A.FWEEK, A.PRODUCT_DESC,      
    A.BRAND_DESC, A.TYPE_DESC, A.CUSTOMER_TYPE, A.DPS_TYPE, A.PPD_PARTS,  
    A.DISPATCHES, A.REPEATS, A.WITHIN_1HR,
    'INIT_ONSITE' =  CASE 
                       WHEN (C.ONSITE = 'Y') THEN 'ONSITE'
                       ELSE 'NOT ONSITE'
                     END
    -- 'NEXT_ONSITE' =  CASE 
    --                     WHEN (D.ONSITE = 'Y' AND B.PPD_PARTS = 0) THEN 'ONSITE WITH NO PARTS'
    --                     ELSE 'N'
    --                  END
FROM 
    dbo.RD_Noise_FY13 A
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.RD_Noise_FY13 B ON A.NEXTDPS = B.DPSNUM
INNER JOIN 
    COMMON.DBO.TLKP_DPSTYPES C ON A.DPS_TYPE = C.DPSTYPE
--INNER JOIN 
--  COMMON.DBO.TLKP_DPSTYPES D ON B.DPS_TYPE = D.DPSTYPE
```

Right now I have commented the `NEXT_ONSITE` case statement portion...but if I uncomment that then it gives an error

> Cannot convert nvarchar to float

Can you please help me with these 2 errors ? I have run similar queries but never got such a problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Whats the fieldname - you missed telling us that.

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product...

Comment: Where are you getting the error? When you run the query with SSMS? Or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of stuff missing here:

- What is `Fieldname`?
- Where is the rest of the query?  Your commented out section mentions `D.ONSITE` but there is no `D` table in your posted `FROM` section

For the first I'm guessing you reference `Fieldname` instead of the actual fieldname in the section you aren't showing us.

For the second, is `D.ONSITE` a `float`?  We need to know datatypes for a precise answer.

Comment: For all the fields - I have a message coming up as "Multipart identifier not bound" - so I just put "fieldname" as a generic term. I have commented the table D sql too, if u check the last line of my sql code. SO ones I un comment all of those - it gives me an error "cannot convert nvarchar to float" - the ONSITE values are either "Y" or "N" - so wonder how it can be a float ???

Comment: OK, so you need to post your table structure and field types as well.  Something is going on that you aren't telling us.